# for loop is making first 2 rows 0 and doing the 3rd right.

Tags: matlab

I have a cell array like so:

`x={rand(901,160),rand(901,160),rand(901,160)};`

and I'm trying to collapse down each matrix into a single row using this:

```
for i = size(x,2)
        y_concat(i,:)= (x{i}(:)')
end
```

what's happening is that the first two rows are 0's and the 3rd is correct.

If i run each matrix indivually, it works fine i.e:

```
y_concat(1,:)= (x{1}(:)')

y_concat(2,:)= (x{2}(:)')

y_concat(3,:)= (x{3}(:)')
```

What am I missing? besides, the  correct way of doing it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your loop only executes once for `i = size(x, 2)`. You need to loop for each value between `1` and `size(x, 2)` so you must first create that array of values using the colon operator:

```
for k = 1:size(x, 2)
    y_concat(k,:) = x{k}(:).'
end
```

The reason that the first two rows are all `0`'s is because you only explicitly assign to the last row, and MATLAB implicitly fills the other rows with `0` values.

Another alternative to the loop could be something like:

```
y_concat = reshape(cat(3, x{:}), [], numel(x)).';
```

Comment: Wow. I'm embarrassed I missed that. Thank you

Comment: @TedMosby See my update if you would like to avoid the loop altogether.